# How to use signalling mechanism for performing intensive work (that do not overlap) with a thread and manualresetevent in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an existing application with 1 thread running some intensive work in the background every `numOfMinutesInterval`. This was previously done using `Thread.Sleep` (sleeping for the entire interval period) but I've read that Thread.Sleep is evil and it's sloppy design, so I wanna change to a signalling mechanism. Below is the code I just wrote (using dispatcher timer from wpf, but I think in this small scenario it's the same for winforms timer as well).

The dispatcher (running in the UI thread) ticks every second, and inside the tick function it checks whether interval has passed, and if so, it will signal the manualresetevent `Set()`. I'm wondering if this is bad design if the intensive work extends pass the interval period? If I set the `numOfMinutesInterval = 1`, but the work took 1 minute and 1 second, does that mean we'll skip 1 `set()` call, since the tick is attempting to `set()` the event while work is still being done and the worker thread is not yet blocking.

Please notice also that I've set `lastWorkDoneTime = DateTime.Now;` after calling `Set()`, should I move it to the worker thread instead (calling `lastWorkDoneTime = DateTime.Now;` just before `manualResetEvent.WaitOne();`)?

If this is bad design, what should I do to change it? Thanks for reading!

```
//thread work done here
private void MyDoWork_ThreadStart() 
{
  while(FlagApplicationStillRunning == true)
  {
    //do the intensive work here
    manualResetEvent.WaitOne();
  }
}


// tick every second
private int numOfMinutesInterval = 1;
private DateTime lastWorkDoneTime = DateTime.Now;
private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  if((DateTime.Now - lastWorkDoneTime).Minutes > numOfMinutesInterval)
  {
    manualResetEvent.Set();
    lastWorkDoneTime = DateTime.Now;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are not ahead with this code.  The principal issue with Thread.Sleep() is that you are wasting a valuable system resource with doing nothing.  You have not fixed that waste.  You can replace all of this by passing a timeout to WaitOne().

Comment: 'I've read that Thread.Sleep is evil and it's sloppy design' - read better books/sites.  Just because a chef's knife can be misused as a weapon is not good reson for banning them.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you elaborate? Does it mean setting the interval wait time in manualResetEvent.WaitOne as the time span in minutes? This sounds like a very efficient and easy way to do the time waiting interval all in the same thread using only 1 statement. Should I do this?

Comment: Yes, it is very simple and a wholeheckofalot better than what you got now.  Now you can use that event for a better purpose and get rid of that buggy FlagApplicationStillRunning variable.  Call the Set() method when the thread should exit.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm using your suggestion now and it's working well. Please post as answer? I wanna use your suggestion as the answer.

Comment: @HansPassant why do you think using a bool flag across threads is buggy? How about using it for clean up code prior to exit (if the flag can only change state once)?

Comment: @HansPassant I was thinking, maybe it's not right for me to run my worker thread on a while loop using `while(FlagApplicationStillRunning == true)`, what do you think I should use instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could just start a task and have that perform the intensive work.

```
private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if ((DateTime.Now - lastWorkDoneTime).Minutes > numOfMinutesInterval)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(DoIntensiveWork());
        lastWorkDoneTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

As far as setting the `lastWorkDoneTime` that is up to you.  If you set it in what fires off the task, you have the possibility of two or more tasks running at the same time performing the work.  If you set it at the end of the function performing the work you introduce a delay that is based on how long it takes to complete the work.

I would actually look into using one of the timer objects and let that handle the timing for you instead of using the `DispatcherTimer_Tick` event.  There is [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx), [`System.Threading.Timers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx), and others.

To help determine what timer option would work best for you:
[Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)